# My app crashes on this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(HubPage));, but only on some phones. Any idea why?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Well I tried to develop an app for a local event. https://www.windowsphone.com/pl-pl/store/app/juwenalia-pwr-2015/d6ec4ee5-9360-4140-bdeb-3893c93e045a As it turned out, on some phones the app works, on some it just... doesn't want to open a hub page. I did put the `this.Frame.Navigate` as an async:

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(HubPage), "7"));
}
```

But still, It shows no signs of working on some WP phones. Did someone had some issue like that?

Just to make sure: I already tried NOT using async's everywhere: it didn't work out for me.

Comment: You need to figure out what sort of exception you are getting -- based on your description alone, it's very hard to say anything meaningful.

Comment: The thing is, it's hard to get to people experiancing the problem-I literaly get no exception at all in any way I try to replicate the bug.

Comment: I understand -- you really don't have much choice apart from introducing some sort of instrumetation. Logging, remote error reporting or whatnot.